# How to import a scaffolded AngulaJS Project into Eclipse Luna?

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, node.js, tomcat, yeoman

I'm building a 3-Tiers Architecture Application by using technologies such as Jersey(api) and eclipselink as ORM. The IDE i use is Eclipse. I decided for the Presentation Tier to use AngularJS.

Actually i'm new to AngularJS and NodeJS. After i created an AngularJS Project using yeoman, i wanted to import it into Eclipse, but that seems not to work.

The picture show actually the imported files. This what i have done :

1. I installed all needed AngularJS and NodeJS Plugins in eclipse.
2. I created a static web project
3. Imported the files into the project
4. I converted the Project to an Angular Project

But after that im trying to start the project in different ways without success.

**How to import a scaffolded angularjs into eclipse and start it?!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give my solution. I found out that a lot of generator for yeoman exists. For my purpose, i end up with JHipster. So just use yeoman to generate the AngularJS project and if you need JAVA Backend just choose a generator like jhipster.